# TensorFlow : slow startup

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow

I use PyCharm and I'm a new one in python.

After 2 days to figure out how tensorflow works I succeed, but the startup time is slow.
Everything is ok before the sentence : 'Adding visible gpu device : 0' which takes like 7/8 minutes.

I searched and tried things like the export CUDA_CACHE_MAXSIZE and CUDA_FORCE_PTX_JIT=1 but it doesn't work, I'm a beginner in python specially in tensorflow so I'm looking for a pretty clear solution of course if the solution exists.

So if someone has a solution please let me know I will be grateful for this.

Have a nice day and sorry for my English.

System info :
Windows 10 x64, Gtx 1060, i5, 16Go RAM
Python 3.8.7
Cuda v10.1
Tensorflow 2.2.0
cuDNN 7.6

EDIT :
I'm learning from 'freecodchamp' in YouTube so I followed a little bit the beginning code

here is my source code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
import tensorflow_datasets
import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

tensor1 = tf.ones([2, 3])  # shape 2x3 
print('shape tensor 1 = ', tf.shape(tensor1))  # Doing some test for learning
tensor2 = tf.reshape(tensor1, [1, 2, 3])
print('shape tensor 2 = ', tf.shape(tensor2))
tensor1 = tf.reshape(tensor1, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6])
print('shape tensor 1 reshaped = ', tf.shape(tensor1))
```

output :

```
2021-01-04 10:04:31.355144: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-04 10:04:43.401510: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-01-04 10:04:43.498316: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1060 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.6705GHz coreCount: 10 deviceMemorySize: 3.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.99GiB/s
2021-01-04 10:04:43.499195: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-04 10:04:43.548183: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-01-04 10:04:43.583967: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-04 10:04:43.595863: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-04 10:04:43.637187: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-04 10:04:43.668089: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-01-04 10:04:43.773909: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-01-04 10:04:43.774488: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-01-04 10:04:43.779002: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2021-01-04 10:04:43.820840: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x16676079d90 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2021-01-04 10:04:43.821794: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2021-01-04 10:04:43.824342: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1060 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.6705GHz coreCount: 10 deviceMemorySize: 3.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.99GiB/s
2021-01-04 10:04:43.825340: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-01-04 10:04:43.825837: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-01-04 10:04:43.826331: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-04 10:04:43.826816: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-04 10:04:43.827303: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-04 10:04:43.827801: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-01-04 10:04:43.828297: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-01-04 10:04:43.828914: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-01-04 10:16:39.045025: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-01-04 10:16:39.045537: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0 
2021-01-04 10:16:39.045836: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N 
2021-01-04 10:16:39.047684: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2095 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2021-01-04 10:16:39.056201: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1661e481430 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2021-01-04 10:16:39.056798: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 1060, Compute Capability 6.1
shape tensor 1 =  tf.Tensor([2 3], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
shape tensor 2 =  tf.Tensor([1 2 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
shape tensor 1 reshaped =  tf.Tensor([1 1 1 1 1 6], shape=(6,), dtype=int32)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**As you can see between line "Adding visible gpu devices :0 " and the next one it took 12 minutes**
Everything is running ok I just want to run it faster because I can't want that long every time I run this program.

Comment: Fabien, first of all, welcome to tensorflow and second, your English is perfect ! we all speak different languages and as long as we can understand each other, that is what matters. It is very important that you provide detailed information of your issue. The source code, the output , etc. otherwise it is almost impossible for anyone in the stackoverflow community to help you. Please update your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same error with Win10 and tensorflow==2.3. Could be fixed by switching to tensorflow==2.4

Alternatively, you could probably switch to Linux. I have the feeling that it is simply much better supported (and tested) by tensorflow.